# Google EMM APIs return The caller is not registered as an MDM

Tags: android, mdm, android-for-work

I'm now testing the Google EMM Apis and I'm trying to generate a signup url for enrolling an enterprise.

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidenterprise']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'my_key.json', scopes)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

API = 'androidenterprise'
VERSION = 'v1'
SERVICE = discovery.build(API, VERSION, http=http_auth)

response = SERVICE.enterprises().generateSignupUrl(callbackUrl='http://www.my_site.com').execute()
```

However, I'm getting as a response a forbidden 403 response code with the following message: "The caller is not registered as an MDM.".

On the Google Admin console, Android for Work is enabled.

I also applied for the EMM Community here:
https://connect.googleforwork.com/docs/DOC-13121

One week and still no reply so far. But is this related to my problem?

Comment: Have you had any updates on this issue? I've recently applied for this too and am still waiting for google's answer to work on a proof of concept.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately not, I've never got a reply from Google.

Comment: Thank you, did you settle for any other alternative? I'm in need of a method to configure and deploy a set of android devices and wanted to use this API as the GSuite is a very expensive alternative.

Comment: It may take some prodding to get Google's (apparently very small) EMM team to respond. I believe you can create a test project in the API console (add the admin SDK) to do testing though.. That said if you are doing this for a single business you may be better off signing up for an existing MDM.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a master service account of Google EMM API to perform enterprises operations. This is the account that you have been registered as a vendor with by Google. It is registered by a human and this process can not be completed automatically online.

Comment: +1 to that answer.   See https://developers.google.com/android/work/register . I assume the "Complete your registration" is the step that will take a while but that is the crucial one where Google marks that project and the associated master service account key as an accepted EMM.